# install npm package from private github repository npm ERR! code ENOENT

Tags: node.js, npm-install

i'm trying to install a npm package from private repository github of my organisaion with npm install, but i still have a `npm ERR! code ENOENT`
How can i configure my npmrc to say that i would install package from a private github repository + npm package public repository ?

Comment: Earlier i learnt that you can not even publish a private repo to npm. In short You can not use npm to install from a private repository

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in previous answers you need to set a personal token within your profile so that when npm runs it will use your token.

Another option is, you can ignore the file `.npmrc` where you'll add your token.

```
registry = https://npm.pkg.github.com/company_package
//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=my_token_here
```

Answer (score 1):

You need [Authorize](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/authenticating-with-saml-single-sign-on/authorizing-a-personal-access-token-for-use-with-saml-single-sign-on) your [GitHub personal access token](https://github.com/settings/tokens) and ensure it has the repo and `read:packages` scopes enabled.

```
echo "export GITHUB_TOKEN=your_github_token" >> ~/.zshrc
source ~/.zshrc

npm config set '//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken' "${GITHUB_TOKEN}"
```

then `npm i` should pass

Comment: If you need to be able to access the private repo in a production environment you can also create an `.npmrc`-file with the line `//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken={GITHUB_TOKEN}`